can i use context inside custom hook?
below is the custom hook. I am trying to use context inside it. It throws the error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"
export const useFetch = async () => {
 const { city, setFetchError } = useContext(appcontext);
 try{
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;
    const currentResponse = await fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${API_KEY}&q=${city}`);;
    if(currentResponse.ok){
        const currentData = await currentResponse.json();
        return currentData;
    }
    throw new Error('error fetching weather details')
 }
 catch(err){
    setFetchError(true);
    return null;
 }
}

can someone explain in simple list which i have to check for custom hooks. like start with use and name should start with caps. stuff like that in simple ordered list.

How are you calling that hook? It's not a well-behaved hook as-is since it would be doing a fetch as a render side effect.

Oh, and hooks can't be async themselves, of course...

Try passing the context data as parameters instead?

First of all, hooks are basically an abstraction or relocation of logic that is located inside a component. They let you reuse code that is being used in a lot of components.
Now imagine something like:
function App() {
  // logic
  const { city, setFetchError } = useContext(appcontext);
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    try{
      const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;
      const currentResponse = await fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.jsonkey=${API_KEY}&q=${city}`);;
      if(currentResponse.ok){
        const fetchedData = await currentResponse.json();
        setCurrentData(fetchedData);
      } else {
        setFetchError(true);
      }
    }
    catch(err){
      setFetchError(true);
    }
  }, [])


  return ...;
}

In this example I imagined how your logic above could be used inside an actual react component. As you can see, the logic is not directly called inside the component, it's being wrapped in a useEffect, and the fetchedData is being stored inside a state using useState.
As I said above, hooks are a way to abstract logic or move this logic in a separate file, so your hook doesn't meet these requirements.
In your Hook:

You made it async. You can't have async methods directly inside a react component (unless your doing some next.js stuff with SSR, or you wrap them in another function and you call that using useEffect for example)
You returned a value. If you try and put this in your react component, it would not return jsx thus making it an error.

For the simple list, please just refer to the documentation: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks
And to answer your question, yes you can use context inside a hook, you can even use other custom hooks! Just imagine it as a component that doesn't return JSX.
To fix your hook you can do something like:
export const useFetch() {
  // logic
  const { city, setFetchError } = useContext(appcontext);
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    try{
      const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;
      const currentResponse = await fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.jsonkey=${API_KEY}&q=${city}`);;
      if(currentResponse.ok){
        const fetchedData = await currentResponse.json();
        setCurrentData(fetchedData);
      } else {
        setFetchError(true);
      }
    }
    catch(err){
      setFetchError(true);
    }
  }, [])


  return {currentData, setCurrentData};
}

As you can see it returned an object that has currentData and setCurrentData. You can actually opt to not return setCurrentData, but maybe you want to change it in a component or something. You can also opt to just return currentData directly without making it an object. Or even return nothing at all.
